# How to build a conditional include that will run the code depending of the current page?

Tags: php

I have 2 types of header on my website, so instead of creating 2 include files for each type of header, I want to create a single include file with an if/else statement that will display the right type of header to each page.

Here is the code for the "testpage.php":

```
<?php
  $testpage="testpage.php";
  $currentpage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>testpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include_once('include/header.php'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the include file "header.php":

```
<?php 
  if($currentpage==$testpage) {?>
    <p>Woaw!!! You are a genius. you should work for NASA</p>
  <?php }else{ ?>
    <p>this doesn't seem to work. Try something else.</p>
  <?php } 
?>
```

So far, I've tried this:

```
    $currentpage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
    $currentpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $currentpage = __FILE__;
```

I've tried on my XAMPP local server, and as well on my "bluehost" live server, and I just cant make it work.
Also, I created a small test on github, to test that, so if you want, you can take a look, here is the link: https://github.com/nobody7/test001

So, please let me know if you have any suggestions, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the web address that the user inputted into the address bar minus the hostname and protocol (e.g. a request to http://example.com/my/web/site/123, will return `/my/web/site/123`), and is usually what people use to differentiate between different pages when using a [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) since front controllers mean all requests go through a single php script first.

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` will show the filename of the *initial* script that you executed, they are pretty much the same thing. SO if you did a request to http://example.com/abc.php those 2 variables will return the filepath to `abc.php` (e.g. `/var/www/abc.php`) even if you executed this in an included file, it will show the filepath foe `abc.php`.

`__FILE__` will show the current file you are in, this is *similar* to the above, but it will show the file path of the file you are currently in even for included files. So if you have a `header.php` that you have included inside `abc.php`, and you use `__FILE__` inside of `header.php`, it will return the filepath to `header.php`. This is probably not what you need.

Your attempts are almost there, but because `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` returns the full path of your file, you need to somehow only get the filename portion of it, luckily there is a built in function for that already [basename()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.basename.php). So you only need to change a little bit of your code:

```
$currentpage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```